# Rich Datatable Highlight Selected Row When Clicked Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, richfaces

**I have datatable and I want to highlight selected row When Clicked Checkbox (column 0) in jsf for using rich faces framework**

How is should be my jquery script?

```
<rich:dataTable id="modelList" value="#{bean.modelList}" var="model" rows="#{bean.dataTableRowCountEachPage}"  rowClasses="odd-row,even-row">
            <rich:column width="20px">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Select" />
                </f:facet>
                <h:selectBooleanCheckbox  class="checkboxClass" value="#{model.selected}">
                    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{bean.getSelectedItems}" render=":tableForm:res" />
                </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            </rich:column>

            <rich:column sortBy="#{model.applicationName}" filterValue="#{model.applicationName}" filterExpression="#{fn:containsIgnoreCase(model.applicationName,bean.applicationNameFilter)}">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:outputText value="Application Name" />

                        <h:inputText value="#{bean.applicationNameFilter}">
                            <a4j:ajax event="blur" render="modelList" execute="@this" />
                        </h:inputText>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputText value="#{model.applicationName}" />
            </rich:column>  

    </h:form>
```

I am using this css query

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
                          $("checkboxButton").click(function(){
                                            $("tr").toggleClass("selected");
                                            });
                          });
        </script>



<style>
.selected
{

.rf-dt-c:select-checkbox{
                background-color: #f7dbdb;
        }

}
</style>
```

This query work mistake way highlight all rows

Comment: Did you try something so far?

Comment: And what is the problem with this jquery? Does it cause World War 3?

Comment: Where is your jquery that toggles a class when it is clicked? You chameleonize the question, that is not good.

Answer (score 0):

I handle it now.  I used this script

```
<script>
$('.checkboxClass').each(function (index, item) {
        if ($(item).is(':checked')==true) {

        var row = $('.rf-dt-r')[index];

        $(row).css('background-color', '#f7dbdb');
    }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I would say it is easier in the onlick of the checkbox to toggle a css 'selectedRow' class on the row and use plain css to style. No need for javascript like this then.

Comment: @Kukeltje How is should be my css .

Comment: .tbody td.select-checkbox,
 .tbody th.select-checkbox {
   background-color: #f7dbdb;
  }

Comment: Where is the onclick that toggles the class?